# How to connect MariaDB with shinny application in R studio

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, mariadb

I am trying to connect Mariadb with my R shinny application in Rstudio. I created a Mariadb using docker-compose.yml and now I am trying to access the mariadb container using

```
library(RMariaDB)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)

# Connect to my-db as defined in ~/.my.cnf
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
        host="mariadb://root@localhost:3306",
        port=3306,
        user="",
        password="root")
```

above mentioned code but its not working its giving me error

> Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

and

> Failed to connect to database: Error: Plugin mariadb could not be loaded:

Does anyone help that what I am doing wrong here or how I can connect to mariadb properly.
I looked for tutorials but I couldn't find any which explain mariadb with R. if anyone know any tutorial or link which can explain it kindly let em know. Thanks

Comment: Any reason not to use the [RMariaDB](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RMariaDB/index.html)?

Comment: On the [DBI spec](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/spec.html), so `host=` would the container name of mariadb `"Rmariadb"`. Hostnames resolve to container names in compose.

Comment: You're confounding packages here. If you're intending to use `RMariaDB` then use `RMariaDB::MariaDB()` not `RMySQL::MySQL()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install MariaDB Client Library

   sudo apt-get install libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev
2. Specify MariaDB Client Library Path in R code -

> Libraries

```
library(RMariaDB)

library(DBI)

library(RMySQL)
```

> Specify the path to the MariaDB client library

```
Sys.setenv(DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/path/to/mariadb/lib")
```

> Connect to my-db as defined in ~/.my.cnf

```
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
        host="mariadb://root@localhost:3306",
        port=3306,
        user="",
        password="root")
```

3. Check RMySQL Compatibility:
   Ensure that the version of RMySQL you are using is [compatible][1] with your R version and MariaDB version.
4. Check System Environment Variables -
   Verify that the necessary environment variables are set correctly. This may include LD_LIBRARY_PATH on

   Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
   Sys.getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH")
5. Restart R Session

```
--- version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
   image: mariadb
   container_name: Rmariadb
   restart: unless-stopped
   ports:
     - "3306:3306"
   environment:
     - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Comment: I tried to install mariadb client library but still its giving me error "Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'" when I run this command "mariadb-secure-installation"

Comment: It shows MySQL client is unable to connect to the MariaDB server using the specified socket file.

1) Check if MariaDB server is already running
`sudo systemctl status mariadb`

2) Try giving proper permission to mysqld.sock

`sudo chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Comment: Most containers don't use systemd services.